# Axios patch with Django/React: Form-data with non-Form, won't update DB, Postman works fine

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, axios, postman

I am working on project with Django as backend(REST API), and React JS as frontend, using Axios to get from my API.

I tried to PATCH data with imgs and JSON (Form data along with Non-Form data).
**It works fine in POSTMAN** by choosing img files. However in my **React codes, it cannot update DB**. What will be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Here's my React codes:

```js
//init state
    const initialState = {
        location: "",
        avatar: null,
    };
 
 const [dbData, setDbdata] = useState(initialState);
--------
//upload img and setState
   let file = event.target.files[0];
   setDbdata({
     ...dbData,
     avatar: file,
   });

//Axios call
    axios.patch(
      `api/user/update/username=${state.username}`, dbData, {
           headers: {
             "content-type": "multipart/form-data;"
           },
         })
         .then((res) => {
           console.log(dbData.avatar)
         })
         .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
```

[image: works ok on POSTMAN]

Comment: Is your react app running on same domain and port as the back end?

Comment: Have you inspected the actual request in browser dev tools network to see clues it might offer? What is sent is as expected, url used etc

Comment: Ahh... you need to convert dbData to a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to send `multipart/form-data`